# Are there advantages to using __get/__set instead of traditional getter/setter methods except for less code?

Tags: php, get, set, magic-methods

coming from Java, I only have a few vacational visits to PHP. Looking at magic get and set methods, my (Java influenced) tummy starts hurting: It looks as if you were accessing properties directly (although, of course, you are actually are using __get and __set).

So - except for less code you have to write, are there any advantages to using magic getter and setter methods instead of traditional getX()/setX() methods? Should I start using them when coding PHP?

Thanks and best!

Comment: There are times when I have found it convenient, but I'll let others answer with other reasons.  I will point out though that using __get/__set is much slower... about 10 times as much.  I don't know why and haven't benchmarked this myself, but it is documented on PHP's site.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/62383/what-is-the-point-of-properties for a more general "Why properties?" question.

Answer (score 2):

The only benefit of `__get()` is the possibility of less code, but even then it's not necessarily the case.  For example, if you have a set of 10 private members and you want the getter to reveal 5, you have to write `__get()` so that if one of the psuedo-visible members is called, you send it.  Otherwise, you either issue an error (that would otherwise come naturally without `__get()` or return a value such as `null` that may not actually be helpful.

I must excoriate anyone who suggests using getters and setters in general at all.  This usually indicates a problem with architecture. Explain the conceptual difference between the two following code blocks, for instance:

```
class _ {
   public $_;
}
```

vs.

```
class _ {
   private $_;
   public function get_() {
      return $this->_;
   }
}
```

There isn't a difference.

However, as many will point out the advantage of having a getter is that this allows you to modify the return value in some way transparently to make it useful for the recipient.  However, we come back to architecture problems.  You should never have to expose the contents of a class for any reason at all.  Instead, you should tell the class to perform an action (which may vary based on its state).  Using getters generally lends to querying the class' state and performing an action externally based on the viewed state.

I have essentially the same arguments against `__set()` and setters, but there is one nice thing that `__set()` lets you do:

```
class _ {
   private $_ = array();
   public function __set($key, $val) {
      $this->_[$key] = $val;
   }
}
```

This lets you type the very nice `$_obj->key = 'val'`.  Note that there is not much difference from this and adding another method such as `add()` that takes the key and value and does the same thing, I just prefer the object setter notation.

Answer (score 1):

`__get__` and `__set__` are fully dynamic. So for example you can start a database request if they are called to enable lazy loading. Of course, you could do this with getters and setters, too, but then you would have to do this every time. You can also do something like AOP because every property call gets passed through one single method. So all in all `__get__/__set__` offer more flexilibility against time they take to process. You can do really advanced/cool stuff with it.

Answer (score 1):

The advantages are that when you're refactoring, direct assignments / reads can be handled without the need to immediately change the complete codebase too, the code can be somewhat shorter, and people can create strings somewhat more easily (for example:  `$title="<title>{$obj->title}</title>";` vs. `$title='<title>'.$obj->getTitle().'</title>';`.

However, `__get` & `__set` methods can become large and unwieldy fairly quickly, and when coding properly & explicitly, it is in my opinion better to use explicit `set/getX()` methods to make clear functions are called, and the minor increase of code verbosity is as far as I'm concerned justified as one can easily see what actually calls a function and what doesn't. A possible exception could be when you are building a decorator for another class/object, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

there is few difference between getter and setter methods and `__set()` and `__get()` methods! these are magic methods!
`__set()` use when you wanna assign undefined state to a object and so `__get()` also use to fetch value of undefined state! 
setter and getter are used to assign or fetch value of defined states

Answer (score 0):

> except for less code you have to write, are there any advantages to using magic getter and setter >methods instead of traditional getX()/setX() methods? Should I start using them when coding PHP?

Given that less code to write it's already a strong reason to start use them.
the other reason is that you can add a common behaviour to all your getter/setter

```
function __set() {
   //> Do some code in common between all setter

   //> set your var here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing getX()/setX() for each attribute, practically speaking, you'll have at a minimum, 7 lines of code. This is assuming that your opening method brace is on the same line as the definition and you only put a single line of code into the method, then you have your closing brace on its own line.

For a non-trivial object, multiply that by 6 (YMMV). That is 42 lines just for attribute access/mutation. That does *not* include input validation or normalization. For an alternative, check out: https://github.com/metaphp/attributes

Answer (score 0):

There are overheads in dynamic programming (e.g. using magic methods). An old benchmark: [Benchmarking magic](http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/magic-benchmarks)

As PHP is a dynamic (and not a *completely* enterprise) language, reducing code lines and missing some nanoseconds seems good idea in **many** cases (for debugging, scalability, reducing errors and etc).